# Force secure server on select page via htaccess not working

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https

I am using a mod_rewrite to force two pages to use HTTPS, while all other pages should remain HTTP. Currently, I can successfully force HTTPS on the pages I need -- however, when I try to change all other pages to HTTP, my HTTPS pages become unsecure. I am guessing this is because the rule is changing the URLS for the assets which the HTTPS page is loading for some reason.

Any ideas? Here is the .htaccess file I'm working with.
(Note that the ENV:HTTPS method is required on my host)

```
# FORCE HTTPS (WORKS JUST FINE)
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !on [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/index\.php|)/(donate|achdebit)/?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.site.org/$1 [R,NC,L]

# FORCE HTTP (IF ADDED, BREAKS THE SITE)
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} on [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/index\.php|)/(donate|achdebit)/?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.site.org/$1 [R,NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are correct when you surmise that the second rule will force assets (css/js etc) that the secure page requests to be redirected to http. To prevent this add the following

```
# FORCE HTTP (IF ADDED, BREAKS THE SITE)
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} on [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/index\.php|)/(donate|achdebit)/?$
#NEW# only redirect requests that are not for existing files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.site.org/$1 [R,NC,L]
```

or explicity exclude assets by replacing #new above with

```
#only redirect requests that are not for existing files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|js|png|gif|etc) [NC]
```

Comment: It seems that Safari works just fine but Firefox and IE 9 stop recognizing the Https as secure... I can tell it tries, becauce it shows the secure sign for a split second and then removes it. The url IS a HTTPS url, and its not even attempting to show the secure sign. It's removed entirely.